# Rotating tetragon/square with matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, rotations

So I need help with my home assignment. I would have to rotate a tetragon from one point.

Tetragon is given with letters ABCD. A=(3;1), B=(7;3), C=(2;6) and D=(0;2). I have to rotate the tetragon 70 degrees clockwise from point A using matrices.

Because English is not my first language it's a bit hard for me to understand all the explanations, so the more simplified it would be, the better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. First of all, this site is not meant to solve homework problems for you. If you need help, please let us know how you tried to solve the problem and also which methods you have available.

Answer (score 2):

Because matrices represent a *linear transformation*, they keep the origin point fixed. So you have to make the origin the point you're rotating about. Here, you are rotating from point A, so you need to write the tetragon with point $A'$ being at $(0,0)$. You can do this by subtracting $(3,1)$ from every coordinate.

Then, you can apply the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to each point with $\theta = 290^\circ$.

And then "undo' the subtraction of $(3,1)$ by adding back $(3,1)$ to every point.

Comment: $\theta=290\deg$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri oops, thanks for the catch! Edited.